# Experience editor not working Sitecore 8.2

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.2

In a instance of sitecore 8.2 version, when I try to open experience editor for any item under content, it gives me following error.

[image]

Log:

2756 15:55:04 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: Path '/' was not found.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

seeing the below error too:

8248 18:23:03 WARN  Authentication on CES Discovery service failed.
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
Source: System
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Sitecore.CES.Client.WebClient.ExecuteRequest(String requestUri)
   at Sitecore.CES.Client.ResourceConnector`1.Request(String endpoint, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.CES.Discovery.EndpointSource.GetEndpoint(String serviceName)

Comment: Is this an upgraded version? Can you compare your bin and Sitecore folders with a clean install?

Comment: This is a fresh install..

Comment: Do you have any errors in your log files?

Comment: added exception logged to question description..

Comment: And this is a completely clean install of Sitecore, right?  No changes to the \web.config and \App_Config\Sitecore.config?  No changes to the configs in the \App_Config\Include folder?

Comment: yes.. clean install.. I've just commented analytics connections strings, to see if that xDB is causing issues..

Comment: Just to point out, the CES exception probably isn't related to this.

Comment: Can you provide the url when accessing the experience editor

Comment: http:// sc82rev161221/?sc_mode=edit&sc_itemid=%7b110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9%7d&sc_version=1&sc_lang=en&sc_site=website

Comment: Are you making use of a Site Definition? Moreover, if you select an item and click on the experience editor, does the error occurred?

Answer (score -1):

Try to upgrade your .NET Framework version to at least 4.5.2. See the compatibility table:

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164